# iPhone claims diskspace is full

Tags: ios

My iPhone 5S 16GB is complaining about disk running out of free space.
When I check it in settings, it shows me I have 1,5GB free space.

Why do I get this notice? It started since iOS8.
Is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: what does iTunes say?

Comment: If one of the below answers has solved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer to move it out of the "Unanswered" section. If your issue hasn't been solved, please provide more information about what happened when you tried the below answers.

Answer (score 1):

Although your device may show you that you have 1,5GB space available, it is possible that the free space notification is popping up due to application updates requiring a bit more space than that. Try resetting your settings (don't worry, you won't lose any data!) to see if that helps.

1. Open the "Settings" app.
2. Tap "General".
3. Scroll to the bottom and tap "Reset"
4. Tap "Reset All Settings". This will only reset settings to their factory defaults and can often clean out any corrupt preferences that may cause undesirable behaviour. Your data such as contacts, photos, apps etc will not be touched.
5. Enter your passcode (if you have one set)
6. Confirm that you wish to reset your settings.

When your device has restarted, check your free space again. It might have increased a little and you should no longer get the notification that you are running out of storage space.